# How to pass parameters to a job in sails-hook-cron

Tags: node.js, cron, sails.js

How to pass a parameter to a job? I'm using `https://github.com/ghaiklor/sails-hook-cron` because I used `sails.js` framework. Is it allowed to pass parameters? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too late, but you can achieve that by using `key:value` pairs within config files

```
sails.config.mycustomconfig.myParameter = 'johndoe`'
```

or via environment variables like

```
process.env.MY_PARAMETER=johndoe

console.log(process.env.MY_PARAMETER)
// johndoe
```

Cheers